# pl sql ignores if statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am quite new to the oracle pl/sql environment (and quite frankly I now think oracle hates developers) and i need to insert some data in to a table, but only if that record exists in another table i.e. i have a table like this

```
tracks
------
track_id
```

and

```
users
-----
user_id
```

i need to insert these id's in to a third table "liked", but only if these ids already exist in the users and tracks tables so i tried something like this....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_insert_liked( 
 v_user IN liked.user_id%type, 
 v_track IN liked.track_id%type) 
AS 
  temp_user users%rowtype;
  temp_track tracks%rowtype;
BEGIN 
SELECT * INTO temp_user FROM users WHERE user_id = v_user;
SELECT * INTO temp_track FROM tracks WHERE track_id = v_track;
IF (temp_user.user_id < 1) OR (temp_track.track_id < 1) THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' does     not exist'); return;
ELSE  INSERT INTO liked(user_id, track_id) VALUES (v_user, v_track);     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Success');
END IF;
END proc_insert_liked; 
/ 

BEGIN 
  proc_insert_liked(333, 33333); 
END;
/
```

and this works almost perfectly, except it doesn't, it seems to completely ignore this line

```
IF (temp_user.user_id < 1) OR (temp_track.track_id < 1) THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' does not exist'); return;
```

because if i do try to insert id's that don't exist instead of doing the check and throwing my defined message it just tells me there is no data

```
0000- "no data found"
```

and if i insert the values that are in the tables, then i get the success

it must be something very simple, but I can't seem to find what is the problem,
Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: If the `SELECT` query doesn't find an ID, there won't be anything in `temp_user` or `temp_track`. You can't access the `user_id` column or `track_id` column if there's no row there.

Comment: so how do i check that there is no row returned at all?

Comment: Do a `select count(*) into var from table where id = v_id;` and then test if var > 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is pretty much what everyone else is saying:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_insert_liked(
    v_user  IN liked.user_id%type,
    v_track IN liked.track_id%type)
AS
  temp_user users%rowtype;
  temp_track tracks%rowtype;
  v_user_cnt NUMBER;
  v_trck_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_user_cnt FROM users WHERE user_id = v_user;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_trck_cnt FROM tracks WHERE track_id = v_track;
  IF (v_user_cnt < 1) OR (v_trck_cnt < 1) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' does     not exist');
    RETURN;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO liked
      (user_id, track_id
      ) VALUES
      (v_user, v_track
      );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Success');
  END IF;
END proc_insert_liked;
/
BEGIN
  proc_insert_liked(333, 33333);
END;
/
```